# All Combinations of List Elements Characters in VB

Tags: vb.net, list, recursion, combinations

I have list `L` containing variable number of strings {123} {/-+} {ABCD} ...
I want to build a recursive function to enlist all possible combinations of these string characters so the above example would produce:

```
1/A
1/B
1/B
1/D
1-A
1-B
..
3+D
```

Comment: you have a `List(Of String)` or `List(Of List(Of String))`? the items to permutate are strings or chars? the example shows chars from diff. strings are permutating.

Answer (score 0):

If you have three separate collections, you can use LINQ to grab a Cartesian product, e.g.

```
from a in symbols
from b in numbers
from c in letters
select a + b + c
```

Comment: This works if it's a known # of strings, but the OP specified "variable number of strings"...

Answer (score 0):

```
    Module Module1

        Dim data As String() = {"123", "/-+", "abcd"}
        Dim charStack As New Stack(Of Char)

        Sub Main()
            visitString(0)
        End Sub

        Sub visitString(ByVal i As Integer)
            For j = 0 To data(i).Length - 1
                charStack.Push(data(i)(j))

                If i = data.Length - 1 Then
                    Dim q = String.Join("", charStack.Reverse)
                    Console.WriteLine(q)
                    Console.ReadKey()

                Else
                    visitString(i + 1)
                End If

                charStack.Pop()
            Next
        End Sub

    End Module
```